# Converting Unicode to characters in angular

Tags: angularjs

i am getting a couple of instances when pulling a json from wordpress api & tumbler on a  ng-repeat and the data is coming through as unicode

i think i need to convert to unicode?

examples:

```
GRAMMY&#8217;S
```

- should be > GRAMMY’S

  ```
   …OR SHOVE
  ```
- should be …OR SHOVE

any body know the best way to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ended up doing it this way

```
.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    }; });

<h2 ng-bind-html="item.title | unsafe"></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the json, `&8217;` (html entities) should be `\u2019` (unicode).
Lets assume you don't control this, it could be interesting to create a function that writes the output to a hidden div, return the html from the hidden div.

Now I must admit angular is not my cup of tea, so basically ...

```
function convert(output){
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        text = document.createTextNode(output);

    div.appendChild(text);
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

I hope you get the idea. You will render your failing characters in HTML first, to pick them back up immediately and "transformed".

After some digging ... take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery) which I believe is your problem.